# How to drag a Window?

Tags: x11, xlib, window-managers

I can grab a window and move it by keeping <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed. I'd like this same kind of movement in my application, but when the user hovers over a given area of the window, it should not need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to drag it, it just need to click on this area and it will grab the window for moving it.

What kind of X11 event should I send so that on request I have the movement mode enabled? I want to trigger it on mouse down in my application.

Comment: This tool can do it: http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/  IF you look at the source for that you can probably see how to do it.  It uses the XTest X11 extension.

Comment: You should not send any events, you should *get* mouse movement events ans call `XMoveWindow`.

Comment: @n.m. I tried that through my widget toolkit, Qt/QML, but I don't know why, trying to get new mouse position, calculating displacement, and adding it to window position cause it to jiggle a lot if I move the window too fast, hence I'm asking how to do this through window manager capabilities, because this way, it's well behaved.

Comment: You are now asking a different question. Show your code.

Comment: @n.m. Pardon but I'm not, as I said, I want to enable dragging just like I can do by pressing Alt, but without pressing Alt, through any programmatic means. It's irrelevant whether my current code is using Qt, QML or whatever, since I can verify that through the common implemetation, it jiggles. For that matter, I have provided feedback regarding this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927534/qtquick2-dragging-frameless-window?rq=1#comment34403743_18927884) and [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewreply/167904/). There's code there, which doesn't work well for me.

Comment: Please post any code you have a problem with in the question itself. Try discarding mouse events if there are more such events pending in the queue. Calculate coordinates gor such events but do not actually move the window. Also try to use deltas with mouse coordinates you had at the beginning of the drag, not with the previous event.

Comment: @n.m. I don't understand what you're trying to say. In my Qt/QML environment, I just have a new event of mouse movement, and the only thing I can do is trust it. If I trust this mouse movement data, my only option is use it for displacement of the window, even more, how could I not use it to _actually move the window_, what would I do with it then? Anyway, this is answering another question which I have given up. The question I'm asking on SO goes in another direction, which has to do with what the window manager does, and if I can control the window manager's window movement mode.

Comment: @n.m. Anyway, you got me thinking, I think this jiggling is because I'm dealing with mouse positioning over the window, maybe I could remove it if I could deal with absolute mouse positioning over the screen, or just raw mouse coordinates used to position the window relative to the original window position. I'm not sure I can get this kind of data in my QML enviroment, but I'll look into this.

Comment: "maybe I could remove it if I could deal with absolute mouse positioning" --- that's correct, the reason of the jiggling is probably that you ask X11 to move the window but this doesn't have effect immediately. Your next move is then likely to use an incorrect assumption about current window coordinates.

Comment: @n.m. true, if I get success on this in QML, I'll answer this question, or make another one more QML specific and answer it.