# QML - Moving custom frameless window

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I found how to do window dragable, but It was using old QT, I don't know how to do it in current QT/QML :/ Please help me

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927534/qtquick2-dragging-frameless-window
```

It's not working because It using Viewer, I can't use it in my app.

My main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it, It's easy :D

```
MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            property real lastMouseX: 0
            property real lastMouseY: 0
            onPressed: {
                lastMouseX = mouseX
                lastMouseY = mouseY
            }
            onMouseXChanged: window.x += (mouseX - lastMouseX)
            onMouseYChanged: window.y += (mouseY - lastMouseY)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can to it very simple. like below code

> ```
> Rectangle {
>     id: rect
>     width: 100
>     height: 100
>     color: "red"
> ```

```
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.XandYAxis}

        onMouseXChanged: {
            if(drag.active){
                print(rect.x)
            }
        }

        onMouseYChanged: {
            if(drag.active)
            {
                print(rect.y)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have any jittering problem, try to scale down the mouse deviation.

```
MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        property real lastMouseX: 0
        property real lastMouseY: 0
        onPressed: {
            lastMouseX = mouseX
            lastMouseY = mouseY
        }
        onMouseXChanged: window.x += (mouseX - lastMouseX) * 0.3 
        onMouseYChanged: window.y += (mouseY - lastMouseY) * 0.3 
    }
```