# Create custom shadow for frameless window in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I know this is may be possible duplicate of ["Shadow for qml frameless windows"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754057/shadow-for-qml-frameless-windows).
 I completely create a new title bar with different max min and close button and also drag and drop functionallity But the only thing that remains is a custom or just a shadow for my frameless window. I'm complete newbe in Qt and qml. 
Thanks for further help.
My app with custom titlebar
[image]

This is my qml file

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
//import QtQml 2.2
Window {
property int titlebar_wrapper_size:40
FontLoader { id: segoe_light; source: "fonts/segoe_light" }
id:registerWindow
width:800
height:600
visible:true
x:Screen.width/2 - width/2
y:Screen.height/2 - height/2
//x: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth/2 - width
//y: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight/2 - height

flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
       Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint |
       Qt.Window

MouseArea {
    id:dragparentwindow
    width: parent.width
    height: 57
    property real lastMouseX: 0
    property real lastMouseY: 0
    onPressed: {
        lastMouseX = mouseX
        lastMouseY = mouseY
    }
    onMouseXChanged: registerWindow.x += (mouseX - lastMouseX)
    onMouseYChanged: registerWindow.y += (mouseY - lastMouseY)
}
Rectangle{
    id:titlebar
    width: parent.width
    Rectangle{
        id:appclose
        height: titlebar_wrapper_size
        y:0
        width: titlebar_wrapper_size
        anchors.right: parent.right
        Text{
            //text: awesome.loaded ? awesome.icons.fa_money : "x"
            text: "×"
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            font.pointSize: 20
        }
        MouseArea{
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: appclose.color="#ddd"
            onExited: appclose.color="#fff"
            onClicked: Qt.quit()
        }
    }
    Rectangle{
    id:appminimize
    height: titlebar_wrapper_size
    y:0
    width: titlebar_wrapper_size
    anchors.right: appclose.left
    Text{
        text: ''
        font.family: segoe_light.name
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        font.pointSize: 15
    }
    MouseArea{
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: appminimize.color="#ddd"
        onExited: appminimize.color="#fff"
        onClicked: registerWindow.visibility = Window.Minimized
    }
}

}
Text{
    text:"XTE"
    font.family: segoe_light.name
    font.pointSize: 85
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    y:70
}

TextField{
    id:registername
    style : TextFieldStyle {
        background:Rectangle{
            border.color: "#ccc"
            radius:17

        }
    }
    width:400
    height:50
    y:420
    font.pointSize: 17
    font.family: segoe_light.name
    textColor:"#555"
    placeholderText: " Enter a nickname ..."
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    //anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

}

Text{
    id:login
    text:"Login"
    color: "#0084ff"
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.top: registername.bottom
    anchors.topMargin: 17
    font.family: segoe_light.name
    font.pointSize: 22
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by making the shadow a part of the application rather than a decoration from the OS window manager:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    id: main
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 200
    color: "#00000000"
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window

    Rectangle {
      id: rect
      width: 290
      height: 190
      x: 5
      y: 5
    }

    DropShadow {
      anchors.fill: rect
      horizontalOffset: 2
      verticalOffset: 2
      radius: 5
      samples: 5
      source: rect
      color: "black"
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[RectangularGlow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-rectangularglow.html) (like box-shadow in css) is another option.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    color: "transparent"
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window
    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        RectangularGlow {
            id: effect
            anchors.fill: rect
            glowRadius: 10
            spread: 0.2
            color: "#406A6F76"
            cornerRadius: rect.radius + glowRadius
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            color: "white"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: 600
            height: 440
            radius: 4
        }
    }
}
```

[image]